# UIView controls not drawing until animation completes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, animation, uiview

I have a fairly simple app with two UIViewControllers. One is the main view, the second is an options page. When I animate from one to the other, the UISwitches and other controls don't fully draw until after the rotation completes. If I don't use an animation, then there isn't a problem - everything appears correctly. Here's the code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

if (self.optionsViewController.view.superview == nil)
{
    if (self.optionsViewController == nil)
    {
        self.optionsViewController = [[OptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    }
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:YES];

    [self.view insertSubview:self.optionsViewController.view atIndex:127];
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting cache to NO? Caching saves the views as rasterized forms which is probably happening mid draw for the subviews of the OptionsViewController.

Also you should consider using the much newer and better animation methods with iOS5.

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Comment: Setting cache:NO was the answer - mostly. The UISwitch controls worked fine, but the UINavigationBar / button did a weird sliding in. Switching to transitionFromView worked... Except that the real problem is probably that I don't have a root UIViewController, and am trying to transition from the main one. At this point, I think it'll be better to redo the app with a root controller that isn't being used for anything other than parenting the other views.